# Most efficient way to integrate iOS push notifications?

Tags: ios, api, push-notification

I've heard of using Node.js w/symfony, using mamp/phpMyadmin, etc. Is there any easier way that involves less of a set up process such as a cocoa pod for server communication or something of the sort? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a PHP script that uses a simple class like [APNs PHP](https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/). It's really simple to use and you'll find full functioning sample code on google.

BUT you **will** have to write some code.